# Func<T> get result of every single call?

Tags: c#, delegates, return-value

I recently discovered that there is little difference between a delegate and an event. In fact you can "hook" multiple functions into a single `Func<T>`, for example:

```
Func<int> mFunction;

...

Func<int, int> getValue = value => {
   Console.WriteLine("assigning {0}", value);
   return value;
};
mFunction += () => getValue(6);
mFunction += () => getValue(5);

...

int x = 0;
Func<int> function = mFunction;
if (function != null)
   x = function();
Console.WriteLine(x);
```

This calls each "hooked" function, and assigns each value to `x` in sequence, and `x` ends up with the last value assigned. In other words, the output is:

```
assigning 6
assigning 5
5
```

Is there a way to retrieve all of the return values of these function calls?

Comment: This is a Multicast delegate, for invoke every single delegate and retrieve the corresponding value you need to retrieve the invocation list, this can help you:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.multicastdelegate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: This is not a difference between events and delegates.  Events *are* delegates, but with only a limited subset of the operations exposed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop through each `Func<int>` in the `GetInvocationList()` method of your object:

```
foreach(Func<int> f in function.GetInvocationList())
{
    var y = f();
    //y holds the result
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Per default, you only get the last return value. However, you can fetch all delegates using `GetInvocationList()` and then call each individually.

See [Calling delegates individually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451436)